# Is it possible to declare all class members public at the same time in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I've started learning C++ in my spare time and have noticed a cool gadget :

From C++ for Dummies page 176:

```
class SavingsAccount
{
  public:
    unsigned accountNumber;
    double balance;
}
```

From my understand, this should declare all members below it as `public`.
My question is : Is there something like this in C# ?

Comment: No. In C#, you declare scope per class member.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov thank you , If you want you can write it as answer I'll mark it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C#, scope is declared per class/struct member, not globally like C++.

There are default scopes, if none is explicitly declared.

The topic is covered on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx):

> Classes and structs that are declared directly within a namespace (in
> other words, that are not nested within other classes or structs) can
> be either public or internal.
>
> Internal is the default if no access
> modifier is specified. Struct members, including nested classes and
> structs, can be declared as public, internal, or private.
>
> Class members, including nested classes and structs, can be public,
> protected internal, protected, internal, or private. The access level
> for class members and struct members, including nested classes and
> structs, is private by default. Private nested types are not
> accessible from outside the containing type.
>
> Derived classes cannot
> have greater accessibility than their base types. In other words, you
> cannot have a public class B that derives from an internal class A. If
> this were allowed, it would have the effect of making A public,
> because all protected or internal members of A are accessible from the
> derived class.

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that interface members are always public.